# Python, forward slash in URI for API Using

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying an API request with Python.. Its like /api/foo/bar/{name}

The name might be like "The/Avangers". So my request uri is /api/foo/bar/The/Avangers.

I understand that the forward slash causes problems. I've tried using "%2F" instead of "/", but to no avail.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

My code:

```py
import requests

x = "The/Avangers"
r = requests.get('myapp/api/sets{}'.format(x), headers=headers)
```

This is the error response I receive:

```
{
  "http_response": {
      "code": 404,
      "message": "We could not find the resource you requested."
  },
  "code": 5,
  "description": "",
  "details": {},
  "message": "HTTP method [GET] is not supported by the endpoint at the given
              relative path (\/sets\/The\/Avangers)"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a little bit confusing and misleading – the forward slash does of course not cause problems. Can you post the exact input to requests.get, as well as the full error message you are getting?

Comment: Hello, thanks. I am sharing full of my request sample.

import requests
x = "The/Avangers"
r = requests.get('https://myapp/api/sets/{}'.format(x), headers=hdrs)

It returns like below;
{"http_response":{"code":404,"message":"We could not find the resource you requested."},"code":5,"description":"","details":{},"message":"HTTP method [GET] is not supported by the endpoint at the given relative path (\/sets\/The\/Avangers)"}

Comment: @B.Karaduman You'll want to edit important information into the body of the question itself. Comments can disappear at any time.

Answer (score 0):

From your question (and thanks to the added details) I can see that you successfully send the request to the given endpoint. You receive a JSON response from the server which contains an error message. The error message reads:

> HTTP method [GET] is not supported by the endpoint at the given relative path (/sets/The/Avangers)

I understand your question as such that you are trying to connect to your own API. You need to implement the `GET` method for the given endpoint and try again. Your request code seems fine.

If you are trying to instead use a different HTTP method such as `POST`, use the appropriate method, e. g.:

```py
requests.post(f"myapp/api/sets{x}", headers=hdrs)
```

Read more in the [documentation of requests](https://3.python-requests.org/user/quickstart/#make-a-request).